# How can I implement Apple Wallet's "LONG PRESS and VERTICAL DRAG" card animation? (clip attached)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I want to implement Apple wallet's cards animation. When user long press a card, he should be able to drag it vertically to change its order.

I have implemented cards list which is scrollable. However, I'm having a trouble on animating cards while being dragged.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is [what I want to do](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sFYP2EOd-NVSU57vsDzx54RKb0srWBMy/view?usp=share_link)

Here is what I tried to achieve. It's just minimal reproducable code that is different from production code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const bottomSpace = 60;
const itemHeight = 220.0;
const topVisiblePartOfEachCard = itemHeight * 0.4;
const animUpperBound = topVisiblePartOfEachCard * 0.25;

class CardEntity {
  final int id;

  CardEntity(this.id);
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(theme: ThemeData.dark(), home: App()));
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
        bottom: false,
        child: StackedItems(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StackedItems extends StatefulWidget {
  const StackedItems({super.key});

  @override
  State<StackedItems> createState() => _StackedItemsState();
}

class _StackedItemsState extends State<StackedItems>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late List<CardEntity> _cards;

  final _dragValue = ValueNotifier<double>(0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    _cards = List.generate(10, (index) => CardEntity(index));
    
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var scrollHeight = _cards.length * (topVisiblePartOfEachCard - 1) +
        itemHeight +
        bottomSpace;

    return ValueListenableBuilder<double>(
      valueListenable: _dragValue,
      builder: (context, value, _) {
        return NotificationListener(
          onNotification: (notification) {
            if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
              final offset = notification.metrics.pixels;
              if (offset < 0 && offset > -35) {
                _dragValue.value = offset.abs();
              }
            }
            return false;
          },
          child: CustomScrollView(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            slivers: [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: SizedBox(height: 16),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Wallet",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 32,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Stack(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: scrollHeight,
                    ),
                    ...List.generate(_cards.length, (index) {
                      return AnimatedPositioned(
                        curve: Curves.decelerate,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 80),
                        top: index * (topVisiblePartOfEachCard + value),
                        child: CardItem(position: _cards[index].id),
                      );
                    }),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class CardItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardItem({super.key, required this.position});

  final int position;

  @override
  State<CardItem> createState() => _CardItemState();
}

class _CardItemState extends State<CardItem>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      lowerBound: 0,
      upperBound: animUpperBound,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
    )
      ..drive(CurveTween(curve: Curves.decelerate))
      ..addListener(() => setState(() {}));

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset(0, -_controller.value),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () {
          _controller.forward();
        },
        child: Container(
          height: itemHeight,
          width: width - 20,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black12,
                offset: Offset(0, -3),
                spreadRadius: 3,
                blurRadius: 10,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Text('Issuer ${widget.position}'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```